# Submitting form with different input values based off select drop down

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

Hello everyone I currently have an issue with my code and need help and for the most part it works but, there is one or two hiccups that I need help with.

The code below acts like this it starts off with 1 input field and two select drop downs. The second drop down determines what other input fields need to be displayed. Once that happens the user will fill in fields and submit the form. Which then goes to the php file to process values, validate, etc. called newformprocess.php.

The drop down works with JavaScript to figure out what to display and what to hide. So, in the newform.html which is the index page has three different sections each with "Display:none;" code to hide or show depending on drop down. All this works fine and all, it's the next part I believe is the issue but, cannot figure it out.

What happens is with the few validations I have in the code no matter what even filling in all the fields it still shots me an error telling me to fill in all the fields but, I fill them all in already. Second issue if I take out all the validations and leave just one it will work but, when I hit submit and the form sends when I get the email I am missing a lot of the input fields meaning what the user typed I am not getting it's not all of the input fields I do get some of what the user typed.

**newform.php the index page below.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Offer Submission Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/newForm.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
 <div class="form-style-10">

  <div class="inner-wrap">

   <form action="newformprocess.php" method="post">

    <label>Dealership Name:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="dealerName" name="dealerName" type="text" placeholder="Dealership Name" style="background-color: white;"/>

    <label>Which Marketing Medium?<em class="required-star">*</em></label><select id="market" type="select" name="marketing">
        <option id="market1" value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
        <option id="market2" value="Website Banner">Website Banner</option>
        <option id="market3" value="Radio">Radio</option>
        <option id="market4" value="TV">TV</option>
        <option id="market5" value="Email">Email</option>
        <option id="market6" value="Direct Mail">Direct Mail</option>
        <option id="market7" value="All Channels">All Channels</option>
    </select>


        <label>Offer Type?</label><select id="offertype" type="select" name="offerType">
            <option id="option_1" value="New">New Purchase</option>
            <option id="option_2" value="Leased">New Lease</option>
            <option id="option_3" value="Used">Used Purchase</option>
        </select>


    <!--This div section is for when client select puchased as their new opiton....--->
    <div id="purchased" style="display:none;">
        <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_startDate" name="startDate" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_endDate" name="endDate" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_vehicleYear" name="yearOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_make" name="makeOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Make" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_model" name="modelOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Model" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Trim:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_trim" name="trimOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Model #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="modelNumber" type="text" placeholder="14325" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="stockNumber" type="text" placeholder="1234" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>MSRP:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="msrpNumber" type="text" placeholder="15995" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="sellingPrice" type="text" placeholder="12895" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="downPayment" type="text" placeholder="1000" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>$XXX/ Monthly Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="monthlyPayment" type="text" placeholder="$198" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Last 6 of VIN:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="lastVin" type="text" placeholder="123456" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Rebate:</label><input id="pur_input_5" name="rebateInfo" type="text" placeholder="Rebate on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>APR:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="aprAmount" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="termOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label> <textarea id="pur_textArea" name="msg" placeholder="Notes" style="background-color: white;" rows=2></textarea>
    </div>

    <!--This div section is for when client select leased as their new opiton....--->
    <div id="leased" style="display:none;">
        <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_startDate" name="startDate" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_endDate" name="endDate" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_vehicleYear" name="yearOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_make" name="makeOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Make" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_model" name="modelOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Model" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Trim:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_trim" name="trimOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Model #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_model#" name="modelNumber" type="text" placeholder="14325" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_stock#" name="stockNumber" type="text" placeholder="1234" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>MSRP:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_msrp" name="msrpNumber" type="text" placeholder="$15,995" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_selling_price" name="sellingPrice" type="text" placeholder="12895" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_down_payment" name="downPayment" type="text" placeholder="1000" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>$XXX/ Monthly Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_monthly_payment" name="monthlyPayment" type="text" placeholder="198" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Last 6 of VIN:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_vin" name="lastVin" type="text" placeholder="123456" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Rebate:</label><input id="lsd_rebate" name="rebateInfo" type="text" placeholder="Rebate on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_term" name="termOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Residual Value:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_residual_value" name="residualValue" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Miles Per Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_miles_year" name="milesPerYear" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label> <textarea id="lsd_textArea" name="msg" placeholder="Notes" style="background-color: white;" rows=2></textarea>
    </div>

    <!-- IF users picks USED it will go to this section of the form...-->
    <div id="used" style="display:none;">
        <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_startDate" name="startDate" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_endDate" name="endDate" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_vehicleYear" name="yearOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_make" name="makeOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Make" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_model" name="modelOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Model" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Trim:</label><input id="fin_trim" name="trimOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="stockNumber" type="text" placeholder="1234" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="sellingPrice" type="text" placeholder="12895" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="downPayment" type="text" placeholder="1000" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>APR:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="fin_input_5" name="aprAmount" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="used_term" name="termOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label><textarea id="fin_textArea" name="msg" placeholder="Notes" style="background-color: white;" rows=2></textarea>
    </div>

        <div class="button-section"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Offer" />
        </div>


</form> 
</body>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

**newformprocess.php where the form is sent.**

```
<?php 

//THIS SECTION IS FOR WHEN THE PURCHASED SECTION OF THE FORM IS FILLED OUT..........////        
        if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
        {

            // Checking For Blank Fields....
            if($_POST['dealerName']=="" || $_POST['startDate']=="" || $_POST['endDate']=="" || $_POST['yearOfVehicle']=="" || $_POST['makeOfVehicle']=="" || $_POST['modelOfVehicle']=="" || 
               $_POST['stockNumber']=="" || $_POST['sellingPrice']=="" || $_POST['downPayment']=="" || $_POST['termOfVehicle']=="")
                { 
?>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert("Please complete the text marked with an *."); //java script telling user to fill in all required fields..
                    </script>
<?php
                }


        //THIS IS THE INFO THAT WILL BE SENT TO INDIVIDUALS IN THE EMAIL SECTION BELOW AS LONG AS ALL THE REQUIRED FIELDS ARE FILLED IN.....//////              
        else{

            $offer = $_POST["offerType"];
            $typeOfPurchase = $_POST["typeOfPurchase"];
            $marketing = $_POST["marketing"];
            $dealerName = $_POST["dealerName"];
            $startDate = $_POST["startDate"];
            $endDate = $_POST["endDate"];
            $vehicleYear = $_POST["yearOfVehicle"];
            $vehicleMake = $_POST["makeOfVehicle"];
            $vehicleModel = $_POST["modelOfVehicle"];
            $vehicleTrim = $_POST["trimOfVehicle"];
            $modelNumber = $_POST["modelNumber"];
            $stockNumber = $_POST["stockNumber"];
            $msrp = $_POST["msrpNumber"];
            $sellingPrice = $_POST["sellingPrice"];
            $downPayment = $_POST["downPayment"];
            $monthlyPayment = $_POST["monthlyPayment"];
            $lastVin = $_POST["lastVin"];
            $aprAmount = $_POST["aprAmount"];
            $vehicleTerm = $_POST["termOfVehicle"];
            $rebate = $_POST["rebateInfo"];
            $residualValue = $_POST["residualValue"];
            $yearPerMiles = $_POST["milesPerYear"];
            $message = $_POST["msg"];


            $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
            $msrpAmount = number_format($msrp, 2, '.', ',');
            $sellPrice = number_format($sellingPrice, 2, '.', ',');
            $dwnPayment = number_format($downPayment, 2, '.', ',');
            $monthPayment = number_format($monthlyPayment, 2, '.', ',');
            $apr = number_format($aprAmount, 2, '.', ',');
            $rebateAmount = number_format($rebate, 2, '.', ',');
            $miles = number_format($yearPerMiles);
            $residual = number_format($residualValue, 2, '.', ',');

            $form_content = 
            "What Type of Offer: $offer
            If your purhcase was new what was your type of purchase: $typeOfPurchase
            Which Marketing Medium: $marketing
            Dealership Name: $dealerName
            Start Date: $startDate
            End Date: $endDate
            Year of Vehicle: $vehicleYear
            Make of Vehicle: $vehicleMake
            Model of Vehicle: $vehicleModel
            Trim of Vehicle: $vehicleTrim
            Model #: $modelNumber 
            Stock #: $stockNumber
            MSRP:$$msrpAmount
            Vehicle Selling Price:$$sellPrice
            Down Payment on Vehicle:$ $dwnPayment
            '$'XXX/ Monthly Payment:$ $monthPayment
            Last 6 of VIN: $lastVin
            Vehicle Rebate:$$rebateAmount
            Residual Value:$$residual
            Vehicle APR:$$apr
            Miles Per Year: $miles
            Other Notes (Rebate Info, Special Details etc): $message";

            $email_subject = "Online Offer Submission Form";

            //THIS IS THE ARRAY THAT WILL HOLD EVERYONE THAT WILL GET THE EMAIL....//////
            $arrEmail = array('Jonathan <jonathan@mywebsite.com>');


                foreach($arrEmail as $key => $email_to)
                mail($email_to, $email_subject, $form_content);

            header('location: http://www.website.com/thank-you-for-contacting-dealer-world/');
        }
        }
?>
```

** JavaScript File to handle hide or show of the div elements of the form holding input fields.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$select = $("#offertype");
$("#offertype").on("change",function(){

    if($(this).val() == "New"){
        if($("#purchased").is(":hidden")){
            $("#purchased").show();
            $("#leased").hide();
            $("#used").hide();
        }           
    }

    if($(this).val() == "Leased"){
        if($("#leased").is(":hidden")){
            $("#leased").show();
            $("#purchased").hide();
            $("#used").hide();
        }           
    }

    if($(this).val() == "Used"){
        if($("#used").is(":hidden")){
            $("#used").show();
            $("#purchased").hide();
            $("#leased").hide();
        }           
    }

    });
});
```

Again the issues I have are as followed. If I add all the validations in the newformprocess.php file above to make sure inputs are not empty I get an alert pop-up to fill in all the fields but, I have them all filled in every single field I added something.  The second issue is if I remove all the validations and just use one I don't get a pop-up alert and the form sends but, when I get the email most of the forms input values are empty like the user lift them blank and that is not the case cause I am the user and I fill ever field in. Well for anyone that helps thank you very much for your time.

**What the email looks like**
This happens even when I fill in all the fields. As you can see I get some values back but, not all and this is for the new purchase from drop down. When I pick Lease from drop down the email has more values then it does below but, still misses some. And when I pick Used in the drop down and submit I get all the values back so the Used one works fine. Its the other two.

```
 What Type of Offer:New
                    Which Marketing Medium: Email
                    Dealership Name: test 1
                    Start Date:
                    End Date:
                    Year of Vehicle:
                    Make of Vehicle:
                    Model of Vehicle:
                    Trim of Vehicle:
                    Model #:
                    Stock #:
                    MSRP:$
                    Vehicle Selling Price:$
                    Down Payment on Vehicle:$
                    '$'XXX/ Monthly Payment:$
                    Last 6 of VIN:
                    Vehicle Rebate:$
                    Residual Value:$
                    Term:
                    Vehicle APR:$
                    Miles Per Year:
                    Other Notes (Rebate Info, Special Details etc):
```

Answer (score 0):

What I needed up doing for anyone that might be having the same issue is when I only used one form and had all those inputs with the same name='VALUE' in the input element it was overriding the others and showing up blank in my emails.

So, for each one of the div's that would either be hidden or showing I place them all in their own form and it worked like magic for me. Here is a preview of what I did using two of the three drop down selections...

```
<!--This div section is for when client select puchased as their new opiton....--->
<div id="purchased" style="display:none;">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Dealership Name:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="dealerName" name="dealerName" type="text" placeholder="Dealership Name" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Which Marketing Medium?<em class="required-star">*</em></label><select id="market" type="select" name="marketing">
            <option id="pick1" selected="selected" value="">Select One</option>
            <option id="market1" value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
            <option id="market2" value="Website Banner">Website Banner</option>
            <option id="market3" value="Radio">Radio</option>
            <option id="market4" value="TV">TV</option>
            <option id="market5" value="Email">Email</option>
            <option id="market6" value="Direct Mail">Direct Mail</option>
            <option id="market7" value="All Channels">All Channels</option>
        </select>
            <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_startDate" name="startDate" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_endDate" name="endDate" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_vehicleYear" name="yearOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_make" name="makeOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Make" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_model" name="modelOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Model" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Trim:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_trim" name="trimOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Model #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="modelNumber" type="text" placeholder="14325" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="stockNumber" type="text" placeholder="1234" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>MSRP:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="msrpNumber" type="text" placeholder="15995" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="sellingPrice" type="text" placeholder="12895" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="downPayment" type="text" placeholder="1000" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>$XXX/ Monthly Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="monthlyPayment" type="text" placeholder="$198" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Last 6 of VIN:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="lastVin" type="text" placeholder="123456" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Rebate:</label><input id="pur_input_5" name="rebateInfo" type="text" placeholder="Rebate on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>APR:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="aprAmount" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="pur_input_5" name="termOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label> <textarea id="pur_textArea" name="msg" placeholder="Notes" style="background-color: white;" rows=2></textarea>
                <div class="button-section"><br />
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Offer" />
                </div>  
    </form>
</div>

<!--This div section is for when client select leased as their new opiton....--->
<div id="leased" style="display:none;">
   <form action="" method="post">
        <label>Dealership Name:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="dealerName" name="dealerName" type="text" placeholder="Dealership Name" style="background-color: white;"/>
        <label>Which Marketing Medium?<em class="required-star">*</em></label><select id="market" type="select" name="marketing">
            <option id="pick1" selected="selected" value="">Select One</option>
            <option id="market1" value="Facebook">Facebook</option>
            <option id="market2" value="Website Banner">Website Banner</option>
            <option id="market3" value="Radio">Radio</option>
            <option id="market4" value="TV">TV</option>
            <option id="market5" value="Email">Email</option>
            <option id="market6" value="Direct Mail">Direct Mail</option>
            <option id="market7" value="All Channels">All Channels</option>
        </select>
            <label>Start Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_startDate" name="startDate" type="text" placeholder="01/01/2012" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>End Date:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_endDate" name="endDate" type="text" placeholder="05/07/2015" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_vehicleYear" name="yearOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Vehicle Year" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Make:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_make" name="makeOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Make" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Model:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_model" name="modelOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Model" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Trim:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_trim" name="trimOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="Trim of Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Model #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_model#" name="modelNumber" type="text" placeholder="14325" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Stock #:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_stock#" name="stockNumber" type="text" placeholder="1234" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>MSRP:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_msrp" name="msrpNumber" type="text" placeholder="$15,995" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Selling Price:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_selling_price" name="sellingPrice" type="text" placeholder="12895" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Down Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_down_payment" name="downPayment" type="text" placeholder="1000" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>$XXX/ Monthly Payment:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_monthly_payment" name="monthlyPayment" type="text" placeholder="198" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Last 6 of VIN:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_vin" name="lastVin" type="text" placeholder="123456" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Rebate:</label><input id="lsd_rebate" name="rebateInfo" type="text" placeholder="Rebate on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Term:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_term" name="termOfVehicle" type="text" placeholder="ARP on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Residual Value:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_residual_value" name="residualValue" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Miles Per Year:<em class="required-star">*</em></label><input id="lsd_miles_year" name="milesPerYear" type="text" placeholder="Residual Payment on Vehicle" style="background-color: white;"/>
            <label>Other Notes(Rebate Info, Special Details etc):</label> <textarea id="lsd_textArea" name="msg" placeholder="Notes" style="background-color: white;" rows=2></textarea>
        <div class="button-section"><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Offer" />
        </div>  
    </form> 
</div>
```